# NPM won't install on Node v0.7.0-pre

Tags: node.js, npm

I've just installed Node.js off the main branch and when doing the one line install for NPM I get:

```
user:joyent-node-4b3824b simpleton$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  101  7184  101  7184    0     0   3213      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  6193
tar=/usr/bin/tar
version:
bsdtar 2.6.2 - libarchive 2.6.2
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.0.106.tgz
You need node 0.4 || 0.5 || 0.6 to run this program.
node --version reports: v0.7.0-pre
Please upgrade node before continuing.
It failed
```

Is there a hack for this or should I downgrade Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* want to be on the bleeding edge (not that'd I particularly recommend it) you could [check out & install npm from the tar-js branch](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/tree/tar-js), which [appears to support node 0.7](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/tar-js/package.json#L77).

Personally, though, I'd just stick with node 0.6.